# Differentiating an integral of vectors

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis

Q: What is 
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}\int_{x_i}( a_{ij} (t)x_j + b_i(t))$$

where $a_{ij} =\begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$,   $\vec{x}= \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$  and $\vec{b}= \begin{bmatrix} b_1\\ b_2 \end{bmatrix}$ , where $a$ and $b$ depend on $t$ ?

Not sure how to approach this expression .. the einstein notation is somewhat confusing

Comment: What is your domain of integration? You just wrote $x_j$? Which variable are you integrating? Is it $dt$ or $dx_j$?

Comment: integrating wrt $x_i$ over arbitary domain, but we can assume unit disk

Comment: If you integrate out the $x_i$ you are left with a (vector-valued) function of $t$, so the derivatives wrt $x_i$ are trivially zero?